# JQuery button click Issue with textboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, button, click

I am trying to cleaned up the previous textbox values at button click using JQuery Code. But it is show the previous values on click.
This is my code.

```
 $('#<%=create_question.ClientID %>').click(function () {
     var get_firstname_entered = ($('#textbpx').val());
     ($('#textbox').val(""));
     ($('#textbox1').val(""));
 });
```

This is html code.

```
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="label" Text="Title:" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="textbox"  BackColor="Silver" runat="server" /></td> <br />
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Description:" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="textbox1"  BackColor="Silver" runat="server" /> </td><br />
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Am I missing something? Button click is working, I checked it using alert box.
Thank you.

Comment: and why are you using additional parentheses?

Comment: I don't think wrap every thing in parentheses is nice style.

Comment: Aslo please show HTML (limit it to 3-4 lines with the textboxes in question)

Comment: @undefined 
yes it was a typo.Sorry for it.

Comment: Are you sure `#textbox` is not server side control?

Comment: Server side code is useful, but have you looked at final HTML in the browser? (I assume you know how to use dev tools - F12 in any browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch server side control.

```
$('#<%=textbox.ClientID %>').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#<%=create_question.ClientID %>').click(function () {
     var get_firstname_entered = ($('#<%=textbox.ClientID %>').val());
     ($('#<%=textbox.ClientID %>').val(""));
     ($('#<%=textbox1.ClientID %>').val(""));
 });
```

Comment: every asp control have client id at browser end you have used it for create question but skipped for textbox

Comment: @user1627138, have you debugged the script? "did not work" is not an actionable comment - be more specific to get useful answers.

Comment: yap user16.... Alexei is rht  you should be specific with errors you are getting with it

Answer (score 0):

$('#<%=textbox.ClientID %>').val('');
$('#<%=textbox1.ClientID %>').val('');

Comment: $("#<%=create_question.ClientID %>").click(function()

Comment: @user1627138     $('#<%=create_question.ClientID %>').click(function () {
     var get_firstname_entered = ($('#textbpx').val());
     ($('#textbox').val(''));
     ($('#textbox1').val(''));
 });